# ¿Como identificar una palabra dentro de un String y sustituirla completamente con otro símbolo (#)?

Tags: java

El programa debe leer un String proporcionado y encontrar ciertas palabras con las siguientes características: **las empiecen con 'p' y terminen con 'r' y las que empiecen con 'h' y en cualquier lugar de la palabra tengan la letra 'o'**.
Ya que la palabra es identificada debe ser sustituida completamente con el símbolo'#', **conservando la cantidad total de caracteres de la palabra original**, (es decir, la misma cantidad de '#' debe ser la misma que la cantidad de letras que tiene la palabra originalmente.

El programa debe devolver el String completo con las palabras identificadas sustituidas con los '#'. Por ejemplo:

> String texto = "las hormigas se están comiendo lo que acabo de plantar";
>
> output: las ######## se están comiendo lo que acabo de #######

Dejo anexado el codigo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("TEXTO:");
    
    String texto = leer.nextLine();
    String arreglop[] = new String[texto.split(" ").length];
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < texto.split(" ").length; i++) {
        char arreglol[] = new char[arreglop.length];
        arreglop[i] = texto.split(" ")[i];
                    
        for (int j = 0; j < arreglop[i].length(); j++) {
            arreglol[j] = arreglop[i].charAt(j);
            
            if (arreglol[j] == 'p' || arreglol[j] == 'P') {
                
                if (arreglol[arreglop[i].length()] == 'r' || arreglol[arreglop[i].length()] == 'R') {
                    
                    for (int k = 0; k < arreglop[i].length(); k++) {
                        arreglol[k] = '#';
                        System.out.print(arreglol[k]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (arreglol[j] == 'h' || arreglol[j] == 'H') {
                
                for (int k = 0; k < arreglop[i].length(); k++) {
                    
                    if (arreglol[k] == 'o' || arreglol[k] == 'O') {
                        
                        for (int l = 0; l < arreglop[i].length(); l++) {
                            arreglol[l] = '#';
                            System.out.print(arreglol[l]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print(arreglop[i]);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hola. podrias decir donde es que falla tu codigo. Supongo que esto es una tarea escolar, con lo cual podrias especificar donde tienes problemas en particular?

Comment: Netbeans señala error aqui: arreglol[j] = arreglop[i].charAt(j);   que es en el segundo ciclo con la variable j

Comment: que error te tira? la respuesta que te dieron no sirvio?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at vaLin.BadWord.main(BadWord.java:30)

Comment: haces esto.. String arreglop[] = new String[texto.split(" ").length]; y mas abajo haces esto...  arreglop[i] = texto.split(" ")[i];.. suena raro.. y por ahi capaz que viene el problema.. vuelvo a preguntar si la respuesta que te dieron no sirvio.

Comment: Si la respuesta de Alexander funciono con algunas modificaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo un ejercicio bastante parecido que creo te será de ayuda.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
    try
    {
        String palabra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Escriba una palabra");
        String[] palabras = palabra.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++)
        {
            if(String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(0)).equals("P") || String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(0)).equals("p"))
            {
                if(String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(palabras[i].length()-1)).equals("R") || String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(palabras[i].length()-1)).equals("r"))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Palabra encontrada que empieza con P y termina con R:\n"+palabras[i]);
                    int longitud = palabras[i].length();
                    palabras[i] = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < longitud; j++)
                    {
                        palabras[i] = palabras[i] + "#";
                    }
                }
            }
            if(String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(0)).equals("H") || String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(0)).equals("h"))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < palabras[i].length(); j++)
                {
                    if(String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(j)).equals("O") || String.valueOf(palabras[i].charAt(j)).equals("o"))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Palabra encontrada que empieza con H y contiene la letra O:\n"+palabras[i]);
                        int longitud2 = palabras[i].length();
                        palabras[i] = "";
                        for (int k = 0; k < longitud2; k++)
                        {
                            palabras[i] = palabras[i] + "#";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        String resultado = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++)
        {
            resultado = resultado + palabras[i] + " ";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Resultado:\n"+resultado);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("formularios.jFrmePruebas1.jButton4ActionPerformed Error:\n"+e);
    }
```

Si tienes alguna duda dimelo en los comentarios

Comment: ¡Perfecto! si me sirvió, solo tuve que modificar algunas cosas pero corrió muy bien. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Me alegra :) De nada